# Derangements and permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, derangements

> How many permutations of $1, 2,\dots , 7$ are NOT derangements?

To start, do I do an inclusion exclusion starting with the total number of permutations minus derangements with 1, then with 2, etc?

Comment: Why not simply compute the total number of permutations and subtract the computed total number of derangements?  That is, $n! - !n$.

Comment: If you want to use an inclusion-exclusion argument, you need to subtract the number of permutations with one or more fixed points from the total number of fixed permutations.  See counting derangements on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) about derangements.

Answer (score 0):

$5040-\lfloor\frac{5040}{e}\rfloor=5040-1854=3186$ if you follow Numberphile's video on the topic. https://oeis.org/A000166 is subtracted from https://oeis.org/A000142